# What does this icon mean ? and How can I erase it at once?

Tags: geometry

Is this need ?
And How can I erase it at once?
I can not select all by shift + click in list.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go one by one:

The 'icon' you're reffering to is a so called *empty*.
The ones in your file contain no geometry and are generally useless.
You can delete or hide them.

1) How to delete all these empty objects.
Press **'B'** on your keyboard for box select. And then *right click -> delete*.

Be careful not to delete real geometry when cleaning up your file.

[image]

2) You can get rid of those black lines here:
*Overlays->Relationship Lines* and *Overlays->Extras*

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It was really easy to understand !

Comment: Happy to help, good luck with your work.